# How to avoid SQL injection on query

Tags: python, sql, sql-injection

My SQL query construction in python code is:

```
query = '''
SELECT {return_col} 
FROM {table_name}   
'''.format(colA, tableA)
```

When I run Bandit security tool, it says "Possible SQL injection vector through string-based query construction."

How do I avoid it?

Comment: Identifiers cannot usually be bound in placeholders. Some ways to make it more secure (might avoid warning): use a whitelist of approved identifiers; ensure all identifiers are quoted; use an ORM/dynamic query builder; unify the query such that externally provided dynamic identifies are not needed.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert at databases but I use helper functions from whatever database package I'm using. See some examples here: https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/

Comment: user input sanitation. Limiting the use of any non-essential special characters (for instance : minus, quotes...) and prior going to production lots of testing to be sure that the third party tools you used or the functions you wrote to do the sanitation are working as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practices recommend to avoid to dynamically build the query and instead use a parameterized query. But the goal is precisely to avoid what you are doing here: prevent a forged parameter to allow an arbitrary query.

If you know why you allow to query any field on any table, and if the account running the query has only SELECT privilege on the database, then you can ignore the warning: it just says that you could allow requests on any table... what you want to do!

But kindly examine the security implications. In some use cases it may be perfectly fine, in others it could be terrible.